# Jquery Multiple Character Counts With The Same Class Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have multiple textareas on the same webpage that will have their characters counted they will need the same class name. The problem is that I can only type in the first textarea and not the others but the first textareas character count affects the others because each have the same class name I need to figure out on how to have each character count affect its closest textarea only. For example, when I type into the first textarea field all the textarea fields character counts are affected. I was wondering how can I stop this from happening without chagning the textareas class name?

Here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2dytq9bj/

HTML

```
        <article class="review">
            <div class="review-details">
                <div class="review-stats">
                    <!-- content -->
                </div>
                <form method="post" action="" class="review-form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <ol>
                            <li><label for="review-info">Review Info:</label></li>
                            <li><textarea name="review_info" class="review-info"></textarea><div class="some"><span class="count"></span></div></li>
                        </ol>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>  
                        <ol>
                            <li><input type="submit" name="submit_review" value="Submit Review" class="submit-review" /></li>
                        </ol>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </article>


        <article class="review">
            <div class="review-details">
                <div class="review-stats">
                    <!-- content -->
                </div>
                <form method="post" action="" class="review-form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <ol>
                            <li><label for="review-info">Review Info:</label></li>
                            <li><textarea name="review_info" class="review-info"></textarea><div class="some"><span class="count"></span></div></li>
                        </ol>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>  
                        <ol>
                            <li><input type="submit" name="submit_review" value="Submit Review" class="submit-review" /></li>
                        </ol>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </article>


        <article class="review">
            <div class="review-details">
                <div class="review-stats">
                    <!-- content -->
                </div>
                <form method="post" action="" class="review-form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <ol>
                            <li><label for="review-info">Review Info:</label></li>
                            <li><textarea name="review_info" class="review-info"></textarea><div class="some"><span class="count"></span></div></li>
                        </ol>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>  
                        <ol>
                            <li><input type="submit" name="submit_review" value="Submit Review" class="submit-review" /></li>
                        </ol>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </article>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function countCharacters( input, output, max ) {
        var $input = $(input);
        var $output = $(output);
        $output.text(max + ' characters left');
        $input
            .keydown(function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode != 8 &&
                    event.keyCode != 46 &&
                    $input.val().length >= max)
                    event.preventDefault();
            })
            .keyup(function() {
                var val = $input.val().slice(0, max);
                var left = max - val.length;
                $input.val(val);
                $output.text(left + ' characters left');
            });
    }
    countCharacters('.review-info', '.review-info + div .count', 5000);
});
```

CSS

```
*{
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

article{
  margin-top: 1em;  
}

textarea{
  width: 90%;
}

input{
  margin: 1em 0;
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What i've done is binding keydown event to each .review-info class, so i can get this from function context, where this references to textarea i'm actually writing in.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function countCharacters(e) {
        var $input = $(this);
        var maxLetters = $input.attr('data-max')
        var inputLength = $input.val().length
        var $output = $('+ div', this);
        $output.text((maxLetters - inputLength) + ' characters left');

        if (e.keyCode != 8 &&
            event.keyCode != 46 && 
            $input.val().length >= maxLetters){
                event.preventDefault();
        }
    }


    $('.review-info').keydown(countCharacters);

});
```

Max length of textarea is now being taken from html data-max attribute, so u can set different size for each textarea.

https://jsfiddle.net/2dytq9bj/1/

Comment: This affects the other class names and ids if I decide to add them.

Comment: Idk what do u mean? U define one specific class name that is responsible for adding counter to input

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might help you, i have changed your way. But i guess this would give you some idea of what you want to achieve.

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max = 10;
  $(".count").text(max + " characters left");

$(".review-info").keyup(function() {
    var curTextarea = $(this);
    var curCount = curTextarea.val().length;
    var charLeft = max - curCount;
    if (charLeft >= 0) {
      curTextarea.next().children(".count").text(charLeft + ' characters left');
      $(this).next().children(".count").css("color", "black");
    } else {
      this.value = this.value.substring(0, max);
      $(this).next().children(".count").css("color", "red");
    }
  }); //Keyup Function Ends

}); //Doc Ready Ends
```

**<kbd>[Working : Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/2dytq9bj/3/)</kbd>**